# How to calculate the limit that seems very complex..

Tags: calculus, limits, binomial-coefficients

Someone gives me a limit about trigonometric function and combinatorial numbers.

$I=\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n^2}+\binom{n}{1}\sin\frac{2}{n^2}+\binom{n}{2}\sin\frac{3}{n^2}\cdots\binom{n}{n}\sin\frac{n+1}{n^2}}{\cos\frac{1}{n^2}+\binom{n}{1}\cos\frac{2}{n^2}+\binom{n}{2}\cos\frac{3}{n^2}\cdots\binom{n}{n}\cos\frac{n+1}{n^2}}+1\right)^n$

when $n$ is big enough, $\displaystyle 0\leqslant\frac{n+1}{n^2}\leqslant \frac\pi 2$ I tried $\displaystyle \frac{x}{1+x}\leqslant\sin x\leqslant x$

Use $\sin x\leqslant x$, I got $I\leqslant e$, But use another inequality I got nothing.

I don't know the answer is $e$ or not. Who can help me. Thanks.

Comment: The limit seems to be $\sqrt{e}$

Comment: maybe..I only get $e$,.I'm calculating it by lab bhattacharjee's method

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HINT:

$$C+i\cdot S=\sum_{r=0}^n\left[\binom nr\left(\cos\dfrac{r+1}{n^2}+i\sin\dfrac{r+1}{n^2}\right)\right]$$

$$=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nre^{i(r+1)/n^2}$$

$$=e^{i/n^2}\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr(e^{i/n^2})^r$$

$$=e^{i/n^2}(1+e^{i/n^2})^n$$

Now $1+e^{2iy}=2\cos y(\cos y+i\sin y)$

and use de Moivre's Formula

Comment: How do you bring the $\binom nr$ under the exponent in the third line? I think it is just a typo, but I am checking my understanding.

Comment: I think it's a typo...but i 'm still thinking how to do next..

Comment: @Clayton, $$e^{ir/n^2}=(e^{i/n^2})^r$$

Comment: @smallsmallice, Can you find $$\dfrac SC=?$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I got it! it's really nice solution! Thank you!

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: It seems egreg has fixed the typo. See the binomial coefficient no longer is raised to the exponent $r$. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 7):

With rough (but *safe*) approximations, we can avoid the use of trigonometric stuff, that is $$l=\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(1+\frac{n+2}{2n^2}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \exp\left(\frac{ n+2}{2n}\right)=\sqrt{e}$$

where $\displaystyle \sin\left(\frac{k}{n^2}\right)$ behaves like $\displaystyle \frac{k}{n^2}$ and $\displaystyle \cos\left(\frac{k}{n^2}\right)$ behaves like $1$.

Comment: yeah,it's really a quick method to calculate the limit. Thank you all the same! I'll think more about its security.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\frac{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}\sin\frac{k+1}{n^2}}{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}\cos\frac{k+1}{n^2}}.$$ If this limit equals $\alpha$, your limit equals $e^\alpha$. In order to simplify a bit, thanks to the Taylor expansions of $\sin$ and $\cos$ near $0$,  we may multiply top and bottom by $n^2$: $$\begin{align} \lim_{n\to\infty} n\frac{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}n^2\sin\frac{k+1}{n^2}}{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}n^2\cos\frac{k+1}{n^2}}&=\lim_{n\to\infty} {n}\frac{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}(k+1)}{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}\left(n^2-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(k+1)^2}{n^2}\right)} \\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty} {n}\frac{\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n k{n \choose k} + \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}}{n^2\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} - \frac{1}{2n^2}\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (k+1)^2{n \choose k}} \\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{n-1}n(n+2)}{n^2 2^n-2^{n-3}(1+5/n+4/n^2)}=\frac{1}{2}.\end{align}$$ Thus your expression approaches $\sqrt{e}$.

Comment: @smallsmallice: I do show the safeness of these approximations.

Comment: @Vi cenzo Oliva yeah, I got it. maybe after the first"=" the k should change to k+1 in $\frac{k^2}{n^2}$ I can't modify it .It's a useful solution ! Thank you all the same!

Comment: @smallsmallice: Uh, yeah, typo fixed. You're welcome!

Comment: Why does Chris's sis answer, basically equivalent to mine but with no development, get more upvotes than mine?

Comment: @MarkHurd: Uhm... it doesn't look so.